# Input field value returned empty after entering some value

Tags: javascript, input, field

The requirement is to dynamically add each li element as and when user click on "add row" button". And when User enters any value in field1, an ajax call with this value as parameter is made to server and the return value is set in the next 2 fields.

In focus lost method, when I try to retrieve the user entered value, the input field value is always returned as EMPTY or the default value which I set in the source code and not the user modified value.

The row ids are given unique like f1_edit_row1, f1_edit_row2 etc. Please let me know on why I dont get the value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="Rows_Edit">
        <li id="EditRow1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 Field1">
                    <span>Field1</span><input type="text" class="form-control field1"
                        id="f1_edit_row1" onfocusout="focusLost_edit('1')" name="field1"
                        placeholder="1234">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 Field2">
                    <span>Field2</span><input type="text" class="form-control"
                        id="f2_edit_row1" name="field2" placeholder="123"
                        disabled="disabled">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 name">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field3_edit_row1"
                        placeholder="ABC" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 icons" id="btn_row1">
                <input type="button" class="addbtn" id="btn_row1" name="Add" value="Add Row" onclick="addButtonClick()">
                    <!-- <i class="fa fa-plus-square" id="btn1_edit" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="updatebutton">
                                  <input type="submit" id='submit-button_edit' class="btn btn-default" value="Update" onclick="updateBtnClick()">
                                </div>
                                <div class="cancelbutton">
                                  <input type="button" id='cancel-button_edit' class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel">
                                </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function focusLost_edit(rowNo){
    var id = "f1_edit_row" + rowNo;  
    var value = document.getElementById(id).value; 
    console.log(id, " Value:[", value, "]");

    // API Code here

    var returnvalue = "TEST"; 
    var id1 = "#f2_edit_row" + rowNo;
    $(id1).val(returnvalue);
    console.log(id1, " Return Value:[", returnvalue, "]");

    var returnvalue1 = "TESTING"; 
    var id2 = "#field3_edit_row" + rowNo;
    $(id2).val(returnvalue1);
    console.log(id2, " Return Value1:[", returnvalue1, "]");

    }

function addButtonClick(){
    console.log("Add Button Click");
    // Code to add rows here
}

function updateBtnClick(){
    console.log("Update Button Click");
    $('ul#Rows_Edit li').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var rowNo = id.substring(7);

        var id1 = "#f1_edit_row" + rowNo;
        var value1 = $(id1).val();

        var id2 = "#f2_edit_row" + rowNo;
        var value2 = $(id2).val();

        var id3 = "#field3_edit_row" + rowNo;
        var value3 = $(id3).val();
        console.log("Value1:[", value1, "] Value2:[", value2, "]Value3:[", value3), "]";
    });


    // Code to send value to server here
}
        </script>
```

Comment: In your html you have not `f2_edit_row` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` in your function call.

```js
 function focusLost_edit(rowNo){
        var id = "f1_edit_row" + rowNo;
        var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
        console.log(id, " Value:[", value, "]");

        // API Code here

        var returnvalue = "TEST";
        var id1 = "#f2_edit_row" + rowNo;
        $(id1).val(returnvalue);
        console.log(id1, " Return Value:[", returnvalue, "]");

        var returnvalue1 = value;
        var id2 = "#field3_edit_row" + rowNo;
        $(id2).val(returnvalue1);
        console.log(id2, " Return Value1:[", returnvalue1, "]");

    }

    function addButtonClick(){
        console.log("Add Button Click");
        // Code to add rows here
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="shipToRows_Edit">
    <li id="EditRow1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 Field1">
                <span>Field1</span><input type="text" class="form-control field1"
                                          id="f1_edit_row1" onfocusout="focusLost_edit('1')" name="field1"
                                          placeholder="1234">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 Field2">
                <span>Field2</span><input type="text" class="form-control"
                                          id="f2_edit_row1" name="field2" placeholder="123"
                                          disabled="disabled">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 name">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field3_edit_row1"
                       placeholder="ABC" disabled="disabled">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 icons" id="btn_row1">
                <input type="button" class="addbtn" id="btn_row1" name="Add" value="Add Row" onclick="addButtonClick()">
                <!-- <i class="fa fa-plus-square" id="btn1_edit" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
            </div>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: 'this' works. Thank you. Now, I called the API and got the value to be set in the next 2 fields. I set the value as given below. But the value is not getting set. No error too.

        var returnvalue = "ABC"; 
 var id1 = "#f3_edit_row" + rowNo;
 $(id1).val(returnvalue);

Comment: you want to set the value inside the first field?

Comment: @Nini the value is being set to `"#f3_edit_row" + rowNo`; the input is hidden that's why you couldn't see it. use `console.log($(id1).val());` to the value, after the last line on the function.

Comment: Hidden field id is different. I have edited now. Console.log prints the value I set. But its not visible in the text field (View).

Comment: Yes it is not because it's being set to `"#f3_edit_row" + rowNo` and `rowNo` is equal to `1` which is `f3_edit_row1` and is hidden.

Comment: Saw the edited answer. I have implemented similar way only. Please ignore the hidden field. I have even removed the hidden field and I am setting the value in the next input field. It prints the value in the Console.log. But the value is not visible in the view (text field).

Comment: It's visible in `field2`

Comment: No. Both fields its not visible

Comment: I think I have done similarly. But its not displayed in View. Can you run my code? Any alternate Solution?

Comment: where do you want the output to be displayed?

Comment: the third field is `#field3_edit_row1` not `#f3_edit_row1`

Comment: Sorry. But In my actual code, the id is correct. Only the value is not getting set in View.

Comment: can you paste the html code that you are running on your side.

Comment: I have updated the question with full html sample code. Console prints the value. But its not visible in view. I am testing in Chrome.

Comment: remove the `1` from the id's `var id1 = "#f2_edit_row1" + rowNo;` to `var id1 = "#f2_edit_row" + rowNo;` and `var id2 = "#field3_edit_row1" + rowNo;` to `var id2 = "#field3_edit_row" + rowNo;`